# Detect String doesn't include number

Tags: java

I need to detect user number should never include character.

I know this method:

```
    public boolean haveDigit(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there any other better and easy solution?

Comment: Your content and code doesn't match.

Comment: You can use regular expression.

Comment: In the content, you wrote that str should never contain a character. In code, you are testing whether it contains at least one digit.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes, I correction it, Thanks!

Comment: In fact, your title, your content, and your code all are saying 3 different things. Kindly make it clear what you actually want.

Comment: @Sajjad. Still not clear. Why don't you change the text instead of code specifying what you want. Perhaps show some sample valid string.

Comment: @RohitJain in my method, If return false, So i know that `str` has character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class and regular expressions.
This method is equals to your method.

```
public boolean haveDigit(String str) 
{
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*[0-9].*");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
   return m.matches();
}
```

test

```
haveDigit("d9h");    //true
haveDigit("d9agh6"); //true
haveDigit("hello");  //false
```

Next method checks what you ask

```
public boolean isNumeric(String str) 
{
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
   return m.matches();
}
```

test

```
isNumeric("r5t"); // false
isNumeric("100"); // true
isNumeric("0.5"); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of regex here. Currently your code is testing if the string contains at least one digit. If you want that, you can use:

```
// Modification of your code. Test string contains at least 1 digit
public boolean haveDigit(String str) {
    return !str.replaceAll("\\D+", "").isEmpty();
}
```

But as per your text, you want to test if the string only contains a digit. For that you can use:

```
// Test is string only contains digit and no other character
public boolean isDigit(String str) {
    return str.matches("\\d+");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isNumeric(String num)
{
    try
    {
        Integer.parseInt(num);
        return true;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `num` is larger than `int`, or even `long`? `BigInteger` would be probably better option here.

Answer (score 1):

How about (updated version after OP edit)

```
if (str.matches("\\D+")){
   // str contains only non-digits characters 
   // and its length is one or more.
   // If user wants also to accepts empty strings instead '+' should use '*'
}else{
   // str contains digit (or is empty if we used '+')
}
```

Comment: I think you would need the start of string, and end of string characters here

Comment: @Cruncher `matches` returns true only if entire string matches passed regex so `^` and `$` are redundant here (if that is what you mean).

Answer (score 0):

What about `Integer.parseInt(String)` to see if an integer exists.

```
public boolean checkNumeric(String str) {
    try { 
         Integer.parseInt(str);  // parse to check if the integer is an integer
         return true;
     } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
         return false;
 }
```